# How do I test helpers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to build some unit tests for testing my Rails helpers, but I can never remember how to access them. Annoying. Suggestions?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In rails 3 you can do this (and in fact it's what the generator creates):

```
require 'test_helper'

class YourHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "should work" do
    assert_equal "result", your_helper_method
  end
end
```

And of course [the rspec variant by Matt Darby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441298/1152564) works in rails 3 too

Answer (score 31):

You can do the same in RSpec as:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe FoosHelper do

  it "should do something" do
    helper.some_helper_method.should == @something
  end

end
```

Comment: it's times like this i wish i could approve two answers. Would you mind copying and pasting in my answer below into your answer and I'll make it the answer to this question?

Comment: What is helper? I get `undefined local variable or method`.

Comment: I got the `undefined local variable or method helper` as well, and then I followed the instructions at https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-6/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec to resolve. In my case, I already had `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` but forgot to `require 'spec_helper'`. Hope that helps!

Comment: It's also important to put the spec into the `spec/helpers` directory. Then `helper` will be accessible.

Answer (score 11):

Stolen from here: http://joakimandersson.se/archives/2006/10/05/test-your-rails-helpers/

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + ‘/../test_helper’
require ‘user_helper’

class UserHelperTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

include UserHelper

def test_a_user_helper_method_here
end

end
```

[Stolen from Matt Darby, who also wrote in this thread.] You can do the same in RSpec as:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe FoosHelper do

  it "should do something" do
    helper.some_helper_method.should == @something
  end

end
```

Comment: Best to derive from `ActionView::TestCase` otherwise you'll have no access to the `params` Hash

Answer (score 6):

This thread is kind of old, but I thought I'd reply with what I use:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

require 'spec_helper'

describe AuthHelper do

  include AuthHelper # has methods #login and #logout that modify the session

  describe "#login & #logout" do
    it "logs in & out a user" do
      user = User.new :username => "AnnOnymous"

      login user
      expect(session[:user]).to eq(user)

      logout
      expect(session[:user]).to be_nil
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Just one warning to folks using this include <helpername> concept.  If you accidentally put this BEFORE the "describe..." it will work fine in that single test, but may muck up your test suite due to a double-include.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this answer on another thread asking the same question. I did the following in my project.

```
require_relative '../../app/helpers/import_helper'
```