# Testing flash message method in application_helper.rb code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm a bit new to test driven development, and I want to learn how to cover as much code as possible so when I make more complex apps in Rails, I'll be able to prevent bugs from introduced.

I have some code in `application_helper.rb` which styles flash messages to Twitter Bootstrap classes and I want to write a test for the code I have written so if anything changes I'll know about it before it becomes a bit issue.

```
#application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(type)
    case type
    when :alert
      "alert-error"
    when :notice
      "alert-info"
    else
      ""
    end
  end
end
```

My `application.html.erb` view has the following code to show the flash message using the helper method above.

```
#application.html.erb
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What type of test would I write to test that the code in the `application_helper.rb` works, and how would I go about writing that test? I'm also using the [shoulda-context](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context) gem for test writing, but I don't care if the tests are written in the standard Rails `test_with_lots_of_underscores` style.

I am using [Cloud9](http://c9.io) to write the application with Ruby 1.9.3 (patch level 327) and Rails 3.2.13. The repoosiroty for the app that I'm working on is [in this Github repository](https://github.com/davblayn/boarderline)

Comment: test the helper method in isolation

Comment: How exactly would I write that? The only tests I've ever written are unit tests for form validation :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440571/how-do-i-test-helpers-in-rails

Comment: @apneadiving while that answer is good on a more general scale, I really just want to have an example that I can implement to my existing code so I can better understand the mechanics of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class ApplicationHelperTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  context "flash_class" do

    should "map :alert symbol to 'alert-error' string" do
      assert_equal 'alert-error', flash_class(:alert)
    end

    should "map :notice symbol to 'alert-info' string" do
      assert_equal 'alert-info', flash_class(:notice)
    end

    should "map anything else to empty string" do
      assert_equal '', flash_class(:blah)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: I ran that test and it returned `test/application_helper_test.rb:1:in '<main>': uninitialized constant Test (NameError)`

Comment: I was giving the general idea. I've never worked with shoulda-context before, so I'm not familiar with how you integrate it with a Rails app. Do you have other tests that work?

Comment: Shoulda-context can be used in conjunction with normal Rails testing. [This file on Github](https://github.com/davblayn/boarderline/blob/master/test/unit/post_test.rb) contains some tests that I have written for form validation.

Comment: Ok, offhand it looks like your tests are inheriting from ActiveSupport::TestCase. Did you try that here as well?

Comment: I've tried opening the test using `class ApplicationHelperTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase` is that's what you're getting at, and that's returned the same error as before

Comment: Did you also require 'test helper'?

Comment: Ah, now I'm getting a better result